# about type in C++ STL

Tags: c++, gcc

Here is copied from GCC STL bits/stl_vector.h

```
template<typename _Tp, typename _Alloc>
struct _Vector_base
{
  typedef typename __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Alloc>::template
    rebind<_Tp>::other _Tp_alloc_type;
  typedef typename __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Tp_alloc_type>::pointer
    pointer;

  struct _Vector_impl
  : public _Tp_alloc_type
  {
pointer _M_start;
pointer _M_finish;
pointer _M_end_of_storage;

_Vector_impl()
: _Tp_alloc_type(), _M_start(0), _M_finish(0), _M_end_of_storage(0)
{ }
```

I wonder what does `_Tp_alloc_type()` mean? `_Tp_alloc_type` is a type, defined as

```
typedef typename __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Alloc>::template
rebind<_Tp>::other _Tp_alloc_type;
```

Comment: It's the name of a base class. It's no different than `struct A : B { A() : B() {} };`.

Comment: Its a constructor call for the base class.

Comment: @NathanOliver: It's not a constructor call; we never "call" a constructor. However we do here name the base class and provide an initialiser.

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder what does _Tp_alloc_type() mean?

As you can see in this code:

```
  struct _Vector_impl
  : public _Tp_alloc_type
```

`_Vector_impl` is inherited from `_Tp_alloc_type` so code:

```
_Vector_impl()
: _Tp_alloc_type() ...
```

means: initialize base class `_Tp_alloc_type` through it's default ctor